# How to update a db table from pandas dataset with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, pymssql

I need to update a table in a MSSQL database.
The dimension of the table doesn't allow to load the table in memory, modify the dataframe and rewrite it back.

I also need to update only one column at a time so I cannot use the solution proposed in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461959/how-do-i-perform-an-update-of-existing-rows-of-a-db-table-using-a-pandas-datafra) (ie the solution proposes a delete operation of the interested rows, impossible for me cause I can update only one column at time)

So I need to perform something like an update-from query

```sql
Update mytable
set mycolumn = dfcolumn
from df
where mytable.key=df.key
```

in which `mytable` is a dbtable and `df` is a pandas Dataframe.

**Is it possible to perform this kind of function with SQLALCHEMY?**

Comment: Please specify the current input and expected output with an example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a temp table with the key and the column you want to update in the ms sql database. And then make a update call to the server. The following is the code snippet using sqlalchemy

You can use the following way:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname')
df.to_sql('temp_table', engine, if_exists='replace')

sql = "UPDATE final_table AS f" + \
      " SET col1 = t.col1" + \
      " FROM temp_table AS t" + \
      " WHERE f.id = t.id"

with engine.begin() as conn:
   conn.execute(sql)
```

Comment: It seems that you can not use FROM in an UPDATE clause.
SQL statement should be like:
sql = "UPDATE final_table AS f INNER JOIN temp_table AS t ON f.id = t.id SET col1 = t.col1 WHERE f.id = t.id"

Comment: how to update all columns? Do I need to manually `col1 = t.col1`, `col2 = t.col2`?