# How to speed up data wrangling A LOT in Python + Pandas + sqlAlchemy + MSSQL/T-SQL?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, performance, sqlalchemy

(NB I do not consider myself a dev, dba or anything like that, I'm learning by doing - lots of (old) programming experience in general but python and sql are very new to me)

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706278/python-pandas-to-sql-with-sqlalchemy-how-to-speed-up-exporting-to-ms-sql) but wonder whether 2+ years later things are now different.

I have an MSSQL database of ~20M rows, ~10 columns (but I will be adding more columns).

The source data was imported from CSV with empty values where there was no change between rows, so I have just used pandas dataframe to read in data, fill forward and write it back. I use dataframe.to_sql to write to a temporary table (replacing if it exists each time), then use SQL to update the main table. Updating 100k rows from the temp table takes <1s but dataframe.to_sql is taking about 3 minutes for 100k rows.

It will take about 8hrs to process the whole dB this way, and whilst that's OK for now (I'm learning how to wrangle dataframes, sql etc.) I need a speed up of at least two orders of magnitude.

The known speed issues are:

1. T-SQL limits table inserts to 1000 rows
2. dataframe.to_sql has to have a small chunk size (currently 100) if I am to avoid pyodbc errors (including negative number of parameters!)

One workaround would be to use dataframe.to_csv with append mode and then re-import the data that has had all the nas filled forward, but that should be a last resort. (It's certainly doable: the source CSV file is 800MB and by the time I have filled in the gaps it will probably be about ~20% bigger)

Now, I have to do a lot of "signal processing" on the data as time series, for which Pandas seemed ideal; on the other hand I do also have Mathematica and can do some work there, but I would like to have a simple technology stack if possible.

So, given that I will have to be making several passes through the whole db, updating it with results the question is:

**Is there any hope of getting the desired >100x speedup by one ore more techniques combined with Python + Pandas+ sqlAlchemy with an MSSQL backend... Other Python tools?**

(One idea: go the intermediate CSV route and use sqlAlchemy to call a stored procedure to import the new CSV, except I have no idea how to do that.

NB The PC is i8700k + 32GB with GPU - I should also make best use of my hardware? Could I parallelise?)

All suggestions gratefully received!

Hacky code to show that/how I am doing this follows (put together from a couple of files... apologies for any errors/omissions)

```
import sqlalchemy as sqla
from sqlalchemy import func, select
import datetime as dt
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def namedDbSqlAEngineCreate(dbName):
    # Create an engine and switch to the named db
    # returns the engine if successful and None if not
    engineStr = 'mssql+pyodbc://@' + defaultDSN
    engine = sqla.create_engine(engineStr, echo=False)
    try:
        engine.execute('USE ' +dbName)
        return(engine)
    except sqla.exc.SQLAlchemyError as ex:
        if ex.orig.args[0] == '08004':
            print('namedDbSqlAEngineCreate:Database %s does not exist' % dbName)
        else:
            print(ex.args[0])
        return(None)

def Main():
    amDebugging = False
    debugRows = 100

    dbName = 'USDCHF_Raw'
    srcCurrencyTableName = "USDCHF Transformed"
    engine = ctu.namedDbSqlAEngineCreate(dbName) # won't work unless the db Exists!
    if engine != None:
        session = sqla.orm.sessionmaker() # do I need a session in this code??
        session.configure(bind = engine)
        meta = sqla.MetaData(engine)
        meta.reflect(bind=engine) # get info about the database from the database, then we can create a table object directly
        srcCurrencyTable = meta.tables[srcCurrencyTableName]
        connection = engine.connect()
        rowCount = connection.scalar(select([func.count('*')]).select_from(srcCurrencyTable)) # now I'm referring to the table object directly
    else:
        return(None)
    chunkStart = 100000
    chunkRows = max(100000,2) # start small, but must be at least 2 :)
    chunkEnd = min(chunkStart+chunkRows -1, rowCount)
    tempTableName = 'tempNasFilledTable'

    # and the SQL to copy from a temp table; only City and Region columns need to be updated...    
    updateSql = ' UPDATE [' + srcCurrencyTableName + ']' + \
                ' SET ' + \
                ' [City] = [' + tempTableName + '].[City],' + \
                ' [Region] = [' + tempTableName + '].[Region]' + \
                ' FROM [' + tempTableName + ']' +\
                ' WHERE [' + srcCurrencyTableName + '].[Rownumber] = [' + tempTableName + '].[Rownumber]'

    engine.execute(' USE ' + dbName) # without this and the con=engine.engine into_sql the table either does hget created or appears in the Master db!
    print('Fill NA to database starting at ' + str(dt.datetime.now()))
    while True:
        # Prepare a selection; use a sqlAlchemy selectable rather than write SQL as a string...
        s = select([srcCurrencyTable]) # selecting the table
        s = s.where(srcCurrencyTable.c.Rownumber>=chunkStart) # chaining .where().where(), or use sqla.and_()
        s = s.where(srcCurrencyTable.c.Rownumber<=chunkEnd) # adaptation to the table length is now in the chunkEnd update
        print('Dataframe load starting at ' +  str(dt.datetime.now()))
        nasToFillDF = pd.read_sql_query(s,connection)
        print('Dataframe load finished at ' +  str(dt.datetime.now()))
        if amDebugging:
            print(nasToFillDF.head(debugRows))
        if nasToFillDF.empty == True: # hopefully I manage to read exactly to the end of the database, so this *shouldn't* happen...
            break
        else:
            print('FillNa starting at ' +  str(dt.datetime.now()))
            nasToFillDF.fillna(inplace=True,method='ffill') # must do it "inplace" - without it there's filling only if assigned to a new object
            print('FillNa finished at ' +  str(dt.datetime.now()))
            print('tempTable write starting at ' +  str(dt.datetime.now()))
            if amDebugging:
                print(nasToFillDF.head(debugRows))
            try:
                # updating from a dataframe directly doesn't seem to be possible/easy - 
                # This link suggests using a temp table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45630095/how-to-update-a-db-table-from-pandas-dataset-with-sqlalchemy
                # for some strange reason I need both engine.execute to use the right db and engine.engine in to_sql
                # the to_sql works with small tables but fails when chunkSize ~10000 - see this issue https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/250
                # There's a limit on the maximum number of rows per insert to MSSQL of 1000 and to_sql seems to have a chunksize limit of 999/(cols +1)
                # workaround is to re export to CSV (!) with a file opened for append see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134942/pandas-dataframe-output-end-of-csv
                # and see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r for python modes
                # https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html
                # to use in the to_csv mode parameter

                nasToFillDF.to_sql(name=tempTableName, con=engine.engine, if_exists='replace', chunksize=100, index=False) # create/replace the temp table
                print('tempTable write finished at ' +  str(dt.datetime.now()))
                print('Main table update starting at ' +  str(dt.datetime.now()))
                try:
                    connection.execute(updateSql)
                    print('Main table update finished at ' +  str(dt.datetime.now()))
                    # ok, now advance by chunkRows -1
                    chunkStart = min(chunkStart + chunkRows-1, rowCount)
                    chunkEnd = min(chunkStart+chunkRows-1, rowCount)
                    if chunkStart ==rowCount:
                        break
                    if chunkStart==chunkEnd:
                        chunkStart = chunkEnd-1
                except sqla.exc.SQLAlchemyError as serr:
                    print(serr.args[0])
                    break
            except sqla.exc.SQLAlchemyError as serr:
                print(serr.args[0])
                break
            print('Processed to row ' + str(chunkEnd) + ' at ' + str(dt.datetime.now()))
    print('Done at ' + str(dt.datetime.now()))
```

Comment: Traditionally - one way is to get pandas to write a CSV file to disk...then use the RDMS's bulk import tools... (that assumes though the server can get access to the file created)...

Comment: @JonClements Yes, I acknowledge that above; I could certainly do that but do want it all to be controlled from within Python, hence the ref to maybe using a stored procedure called somehow... On the other hand, Python/Pandas is the data wrangling flavour of the moment and I wonder how people really do deal with BIG data (I consider my dataset rather small by comparison :)

Comment: Is there not a more efficient adapter for MSSQL? I know I've never had problems when working with postgres and bulk uploads with `.to_sql()` like this...

Comment: @JonClements Maybe someone else can answer that! That's the sort of answer I would be interested in.

Comment: Just had a quick look and *There are several python SQL drivers available. However, Microsoft places its testing efforts and its confidence in pyodbc driver.* - so maybe not a possible solution...

Comment: The source for the statement that MS prefers pyodbc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)  suggests pymssql, but https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6yvdlm/python_mssql_pymssql_or_pyodbc/ suggested pymssql also has speed issues.  ceODBC was 2 orders of magnitude faster, but the last release was 2011... Maybe I can rent a flock of pigeons :)

Comment: I think some versions of PyODBC had an issue with larger `executemany()` (which `to_sql()` uses under the hood) operations being dog slow and they actually fixed it, but it requires that a flag is set to enable the new feature.

Comment: And here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks, I must be doing something wrong because I can't get it to work - will post a new question with details

Comment: @IljaEverilä - new question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982306/pyodbc-sqlachemy-enable-fast-execute-many