# pyodbc/sqlAchemy enable fast execute many

Tags: python, performance, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

In response to my question [How to speed up data wrangling A LOT in Python + Pandas + sqlAlchemy + MSSQL/T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966096/how-to-speed-up-data-wrangling-a-lot-in-python-pandas-sqlalchemy-mssql-t-s?noredirect=1#comment90886403_51966096) I was kindly directed to [Speeding up pandas.DataFrame.to_sql with fast_executemany of pyODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc) by @IljaEverilä.

NB For test purposes I am only reading/writing 10k rows.

I added the event listener and a) the function is called but b) clearly executemany is not set as the IF fails and cursor.fast_executemay is not set.

```
def namedDbSqlAEngineCreate(dbName):
    # Create an engine and switch to the named db
    # returns the engine if successful and None if not
    # 2018-08-23 added fast_executemany accoding to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc?rq=1
    engineStr = 'mssql+pyodbc://@' + defaultDSN
    engine = sqla.create_engine(engineStr, echo=False)

    @event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
    def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
        # print("FUNC call")
        if executemany:
            print('executemany')
            cursor.fast_executemany = True
    try:
        engine.execute('USE ' +dbName)
        return(engine)
    except sqla.exc.SQLAlchemyError as ex:
        if ex.orig.args[0] == '08004':
            print('namedDbSqlAEngineCreate:Database %s does not exist' % dbName)
        else:
            print(ex.args[0])
        return(None)
```

Naturally there is no change in speed.

The code in my original question is unchanged in the to_sql

```
nasToFillDF.to_sql(name=tempTableName, con=engine.engine, if_exists='replace', chunksize=100, index=False)
```

because I tried, per the example, setting chunksize = None and receive the error message (which I had encountered previously)

> (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('The SQL contains -31072 parameter markers,
>   but 100000 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

What have I done wrong? I guess the executemany parameter of the receive_before_cursor_execute is not set, but if that is the answer I have no idea how to fix it.

Setup is pyodbc 4.0.23, sqlAchemy 1.2.6, Python 3.6.something

Comment: @IljaEverilä statement as it is in the engine creation or for the to_sql?

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes, I know (I've been running it and looking at the ouput) but it executes many times; there's lots of output and I wondered which particular statement value was of interest since I create the engine, read in a dataframe, then do the to_sql output

Comment: @IljaEverilä For the insert itself the statement is "INSERT INTO [tempNasFilledTable] ([Rownumber], [Dateyyyymmdd], [Time], [msSinceEpoch], [Bid], \[Ask\], [Spread], [Contributor], [Region], [City]) VALUES " followed by "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" n-times and then the pyodbc error occurs "(pyodbc.Error) ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')"

Comment: @IljaEverilä what should be concluded from this/done about it then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178602/discussion-between-ilja-everila-and-julian-moore).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you received is caused by changes introduced in Pandas version 0.23.0, reverted in 0.23.1, and reintroduced in 0.24.0, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689082/to-sql-pyodbc-count-field-incorrect-or-syntax-error). The produced VALUES clause contains 100,000 parameter markers and it'd seem that the count is stored in a signed 16 bit integer, so it overflows and you get the funny

> The SQL contains -31072 parameter markers, but 100000 parameters were supplied

You can check for yourself:

```
In [16]: 100000 % (2 ** 16) - 2 ** 16
Out[16]: -31072
```

If you would like to keep on using Pandas as is, you will have to calculate and provide a suitable `chunksize` value, such as the 100 you were using, taking into account both the maximum row limit of 1,000 for VALUES clause and the maximum parameter limit of 2,100 for stored procedures. The details are again explained in the [linked Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689082/to-sql-pyodbc-count-field-incorrect-or-syntax-error).

Before the change Pandas used to always use [`executemany()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#executemany) when inserting data. Newer versions detect if the [dialect](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/) in use supports VALUES clause in INSERT. This detection happens in `SQLTable.insert_statement()` and cannot be controlled, which is a shame since [PyODBC](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) fixed their `executemany()` performance, [given the right flag is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006551/speeding-up-pandas-dataframe-to-sql-with-fast-executemany-of-pyodbc).

In order to force Pandas to use `executemany()` with PyODBC again `SQLTable` has to be [monkeypatched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch):

```
import pandas.io.sql

def insert_statement(self, data, conn):
    return self.table.insert(), data

pandas.io.sql.SQLTable.insert_statement = insert_statement
```

This will be **horribly** slow, if the [`Cursor.fast_executemany`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany) flag is not set, so remember to set the proper event handler.

Here is a simple performance comparison, using the following dataframe:

```
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame({f'X{i}': range(1000000) for i in range(9)})
```

Vanilla Pandas 0.24.0:

```
In [14]: %time df.to_sql('foo', engine, chunksize=209)
CPU times: user 2min 9s, sys: 2.16 s, total: 2min 11s
Wall time: 2min 26s
```

Monkeypatched Pandas with fast executemany enabled:

```
In [10]: %time df.to_sql('foo', engine, chunksize=500000)
CPU times: user 12.2 s, sys: 981 ms, total: 13.2 s
Wall time: 38 s
```

Comment: Helpful. How would I adapt this to use multi option with df.to_sql to upload a csv? + I tried running your  top code bock first before an attempt to use df.to_sql to upload a csv but still got same error.

Comment: Not sure if I was supposed to update this line _pandas.io.sql.SQLTable.insert_statement = insert_statement_

Comment: Not anymore with latest pandas and SQLAlchemy. With pyodbc pass `fast_executemany=True` to `create_engine()` and leave `multi=` at its default `None`.

Comment: Thanks for that.