# export pandas df to sql server if data not exists

Tags: python, dataframe, sqlalchemy, export, pandas-to-sql

I have a df named "review" like this :

| usuarios | fecha | calificacion | comentario | branch_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cinthya De Sousa | 2022-09-20 | 1 estrella | Empleados que te atienden con poca naturalidad. | 53 |
| Luana Antonella Gomez Lucero | 2022-08-23 | 1 estrella | Desastrosa atencion por parte de una mujer rub. | 53 |

I need to export df content to a table in my sql server database so I do this_:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                     "SERVER=xxx.xx.x.x;"
                                     "DATABASE=xxxx;"
                                     "UID=xxxx;"
                                     "PWD=xxxx")
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://xxxx:xxxxx@xxx.xx.x.x/xxxxxx')

review.to_sql("Google_Reviews_sucursales", engine, if_exists='append',chunksize = 1000)
```

everything works fine. When I go to my database I have all the lines exported (98 in the real df). The problem is that this df will be changing everyday, and when I run the script again, the rows that already exists in my sqlserver database are exported again and duplicated...
waht could I do to avoid exporting duplicate data to the table? . The df will be replaced everyday and will have only the last 10 google reviews from a commerce. If these 10 records are not in the sql table, it will be fine, but probably some reviews are duplicated so, next day, if I get the last 10 reviews and 5 already exists in the table, I will be duplicating the data. Is it possible to add rows, only if they don´t already exist in the table?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42468898/11622508

Comment: Thanks but it s not the same. Please read my post